# How can I use XPath to create a new xml content?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following problem. Into a Java application I have to create a new XML content using **XPath** (I always used it to parse XML files and obtain values inside its tag, can I use it also for build a new XML content?).

So my final result (that have to be saved on a database CLOB field, not on an .xml file, but I think that this is not important) have to be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <Messaggio>
        <Intestazione>
            <Da>06655971007</Da>
            <A>01392380547</A>
            <id>69934</id>
            <idEnel/>
            <DataInvio>2015-05-06</DataInvio>
            <DataRicezione/>
            <InRisposta/>
            <TipoDoc>Ricevuta</TipoDoc>
        </Intestazione>

        <Documenti>
            <Ricevuta>
                <Testata>
                    <Documento>
                        <Tipo>380</Tipo>
                        <NumeroDocumento>ff</NumeroDocumento>
                        <Stato>KO</Stato>
                        <Data>2014-03-10</Data>
                    </Documento>
                </Testata>

                <Dettaglio>
                    <Messaggio>
                        <Codice>000</Codice>
                        <Descrizione>Documento NON Conforme / NON dovuto</Descrizione>
                    </Messaggio>
                </Dettaglio>
            </Ricevuta>
        </Documenti>
    </Messaggio>
```

So what I need to do is to programmatically add the nodes and the content of these nodes (the content is obtained from a model object).

Can I do it using **XPath**? How?

Tnx

Comment: It is best to maintain XML documents using a DOM parser. You could use Jaxb which will easily create an object model representation

Comment: @KennethClark No it is not what I need. I don't need to create an XML representation of a model object. I need to create a specific XML that use few fields of a model object and some other information taken elsewhere

Comment: @KennethClark Your statement "it is best to maintain XML documents using a DOM parser" is just plain wrong in this absolutes. Most of the time, XSLT or XQuery (Update) are much more performant, need far less main memory and are easier to maintain. Of course there are reasons or scenarious where DOM is superior, but in no way this should be a general advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is an API to locate nodes in a XML document. It can't create new nodes or manipulate existing nodes. So what you need is to locate the nodes to modify using XPath and then use the API of the found nodes to make the changes.

But in your case, you're starting with an empty document. Have a look at frameworks like [JDOM 2](http://www.jdom.org/) to build XML documents from scratch. This tutorial should get you started: http://www.studytrails.com/java/xml/jdom2/java-xml-jdom2-example-usage.jsp

Answer (score 1):

You can't. XPath is a matching technology, not a content creation technology. Possibly you are looking for XSLT?

Comment: mmm I am not so into this topic but...XSLT is not used only to apply style sheet to XML document? Can I use it also to build a new XML document from scratch? TNX